# Change BLE device name using cordova-ble-plugin

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, ionic4

I am using corodova-ble-plugin (https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central) with my ionic 4 project and I wanted to know if its possible to change the bluetooth device name with this plugin. I searched the ble plugin documentation and did not find anything. But have anyone done such thing with an ionic app before without native android dev?

** Update **

I was able to find the characteristics that has to be passed using the write method to set the name of the device. But the passed value has to be a array buffer type and not string. So I used the string to array buffer npm package, its passing the write value when I checked in the android studio console but in the device it shows up with symbols instead and not the actual name. What would be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Cordova but it looks like this plugin doesn't allow what you're looking for. The good news is if you change the name of the device using native code, it should work.

`BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().setName("myDeviceName");`

You can use that in your MainActivity.

Comment: I was able to find the characteristics that has to be passed using the write method to set the name of the device. But the passed value has to be a array buffer type and not string. So I used the string to array buffer npm package, its passing the write value when I checked but in the device it shows up with symbols instead and not the actual name.

Comment: Could be a encoding error. What exactly is your requirement? Instead of device name maybe you can use custom data to pass the name you want.

Comment: I have to pass a name to change the device name. What exactly do you mean by custom data?

Comment: What I mean by custom data is when advertising with BLE you are able to add service data like 'device name' and 'tx power' but of your own choosing. Maybe you can use that with your own UUID to send the device name. Or you can always write your own characteristic with the device name.